# Call an instance by most recent dates rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I have a set of blog post and I want to display them in order of most recent date. How can I call that method in the controller

I tried

```
@post1 = Post.last
```

but how would I do the 3 previous to this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
@post1 = Post.last
```

doesn't give the last `Post` in the way you think it does. If you check your logs you'll see something like this:

```
selector={"$query"=>{}, "$orderby"=>{:_id=>-1}}
```

so it will be "last in `id` order", not the last by date. If you want the last by some timestamp then you have to say so:

```
@post1 = Post.order(:created_at => :desc).first
```

You'd use some other date or timestamp instead of `:created_at` if you have one that better matches your intent.

Now, if you want the three previous to that, grab four and throw one away:

```
other_three = Post.order(:created_at => :desc).limit(4)[1.3] # or any of the ways
```

Or you could use `offset` to skip the first one:

```
other_three = Post.order(:created_at => :desc).offset(1).limit(3)
```

Comment: Thank you sir! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This should give you what you want:

```
@post1 = Post.last(4).reverse[0..-2]
```

`Post.last(4).reverse` will give you last 4 records in descending order. And, then with this: `Post.last(4).reverse[0..-2]` you are grabbing all but the last element which is what you want.

If you don't want the `descending` order, then you can just do this without the `reverse` part:

```
@post1 = Post.last(4)[0..-2]
```

Hope this helps.

#### Update

You can also do it this way:

```
@posts = Post.limit(4).order(updated_at: :desc)[1..-1]
```

Comment: threw an error "wrong number of arguments(1 for 0)"

Comment: Which line threw the error? could you please paste the full error trace?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention mongoid.